# sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
for i in str_list:   #str_list is a set contain some strings 
    df.loc[i].sort_values(by = 'XXX')
**TypeError**: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by' ".
>>> type(df.loc[i])
>>> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

But it works outside the for loop!

```
df.loc['string'].sort_values(by = 'XXX')
>>> type(df.loc['string'])
>>> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

I'm confused.

Comment: `df.loc[something]` may return a Series or a DataFrame. If `something` appears multiple times in the index, the result is a DataFrame.

Answer (score 20):

This is because the result of the `loc` operator is a `pandas.Series` object in your case. The `sort_values` in this case doesn't have a keyword argument `by` because it can only sort the series values. Have a look at the difference in the signature when you call `sort values` in a `pandas.DataFrame`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

and when you call `sort_values` in a `pandas.Series`

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer, 
why is it returning a series in one case and a data frame in another?

.loc function is returning a Series in the first case

> for i in str_list:   #str_list is a set contain some strings
>
> df.loc[**i**].sort_values(by = 'XXX')

because the argument **i** appears only once in the DataFrame.

in the second case, the 'string' is duplicated and therefore will return a DataFrame.

> df.loc['string'].sort_values(by = 'XXX')

If the 'string' argument is not duplicated then
note that there are also some differences if the argument in .loc is on a list.
for example.

df.loc['string']   -> returns a Series

df.loc[['string']] -> returns a DataFrame

Maybe in the second case you are giving ['string'] as the argument instead of 'string' ?

Hope this helps.